# Global name not defined problem occured when copying flawless code into another code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a uni student summarizing the code for a group work, my friend's code can run properly but when i copy it to the whole file and changed nothing, it just keep returning: NameError: global name 'questions' is not defined

The original code used: from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button. While i used: import Tkinter. But i imported both on the top of the code when summarizing but the problem wasn't solved, then I added Tkinter. before every places might need it and it still doesn't work as well.

I feeling so desperate now, it would be sooo helpful if you can help me out!! Thank you!

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button 
import Tkinter
import math
import tkMessageBox
import re
from time import sleep


def askQuestion():
    global questions, window, index, button, right, number_of_questions
    if(len(questions) == index + 1):
        Tkinter.Label(window, text="Thank you for taking the quiz. " + str(right) + " of " + str(number_of_questions) + " questions were answered correctly!").pack()
        return
    button.pack_forget()
    index += 1
    questions[index].getView(window).pack()

questions = []
file = open("questions.txt", "r")
line = file.readline()
while(line != ""):
    questionString = line
    answers = []
    for i in range (4):
        answers.append(file.readline())

    correctLetter = file.readline()
    correctLetter = correctLetter[:-1]
    questions.append(Question(questionString, answers, correctLetter))
    line = file.readline()
file.close()
```

I'm trying to create an empty dictionary and let it read the quiz file that i've prepared, i expect the 'questions' could read the file but it shows: NameError: global name 'questions' is not defined

Comment: Can you please copy-and-paste your code into the question, highlight it, then press ctrl-k so we know *exactly* the indentation you are using. I tried to fix it but I think I just messed it up

Comment: Your posted code fails for lack of the input file.
With that fixed, it fails because there is no definition for class `Question`.

Comment: That's not what happens when you run the code you've posted. It might say something about `Question`, which you try to use despite never defining anywhere, but not `questions`. Please post something that we can run, that reproduces the problem when run, as well as the *complete, exact* error message that code produces, including full stack trace.

Comment: Ahhhh copy and paste - the enemy of learning. Perhaps try to understand what your group friends have actually coded (or better yet, ask them), then you won't need us.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have your global variables defined before the method that uses them.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but no, you don't. You can define the *function* and the *global variable* anywhere, as long as the *function isn't called before the global variable exists*

Comment: But it ran properly before been copied to another file, so I don't think it's the problem.